# Problems in dragging images in Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview, draggable

I have to load images into gridview and i should be able to drag & drop those images in a gridview. I have used the following two classes.  https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView/tree/master/src/com/animoto/android/views. And i have added this in my activity file

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dgv = (DraggableGridView)findViewById(R.id.dgv);

    loadImages();


}   

private void loadImages() {

    int images[] = {R.drawable.p_1, R.drawable.p_2, R.drawable.p_3, R.drawable.p_4, R.drawable.p_5, R.drawable.p_6};

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[i]));
        dgv.addView(iv);
    }




}
```

Now iam able to drag & drop images in gridview.
Here are my problems
1. How do i fix only 3 images in a row.
 
2. How do i know my images place on click of a button. After dragging & dropping, How do i get the position of each image? (i.e i want to know the position/cell_number of each image) 
3. How can i have different background views for images. I just need to show the number of each image postion in the background when the user picks up it to drag. The Background view (which represents postion of image) shoud not move when he picks up the image to drag.
Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably getting in a little late here, but you'll have to make some changes to the grid view to get more/less images per column. Import the project as a library project and make any changes you need.
2. Sounds like you're going to want to use DGV's setOnItemClickListener and setOnRearrangeListener. Check out the sample project for an example.
3. Again, see the sample project for one way of how to do that.